# How to count number of orders from a list of certain dates

Tags: filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this sample sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-Zr1ij6KbKbL5IHrVYBNPWmWSWkntZz9amrNBInQY6c/edit?usp=sharing

I need to count the number of orders from both tabs for certain dates: Today, Yesterday, Last 30 days, This month, Last Month, This month last year

result in Tab "Stats"

how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

[image: 0]

**F4:**

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER({V!D4:D;Ventas!D4:D}, {V!A4:A;Ventas!A4:A}=TODAY())))
```

**F5:**

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER({V!D4:D;Ventas!D4:D}, {V!A4:A;Ventas!A4:A}=TODAY()-1)))
```

**F6:**

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER({V!D4:D;Ventas!D4:D}, {V!A4:A;Ventas!A4:A}<=TODAY(), 
 {V!A4:A;Ventas!A4:A}>=TODAY()-30)))
```

**F7:**

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER({V!D4:D;Ventas!D4:D}, 
 YEAR({V!A4:A;Ventas!A4:A})=YEAR(TODAY()), 
 MONTH({V!A4:A;Ventas!A4:A})=MONTH(TODAY()))))
```

**F8:**

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER({V!D4:D;Ventas!D4:D}, 
 YEAR({V!A4:A;Ventas!A4:A})=YEAR(TODAY()), 
 MONTH({V!A4:A;Ventas!A4:A})=MONTH(TODAY())-1)))
```

**F9:**

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER({V!D4:D;Ventas!D4:D}, 
 YEAR({V!A4:A;Ventas!A4:A})=YEAR(TODAY())-1, 
 MONTH({V!A4:A;Ventas!A4:A})=MONTH(TODAY()))))
```

Comment: its not counting the # of orders, for example, one client can have multiple orders in a day or in a month

Comment: I appreciate your time, but you are counting the number of products, not the number of orders, and that's what im looking for

Comment: its now giving me the correct answer ;( ... I was coming to an approach of =COUNTUNIQUE(filter(Ventas!A4:A&Ventas!$B$4:$B,(DATE(YEAR(Ventas!A4:A), MONTH(Ventas!A4:A), 1)=DATE(YEAR(today()), MONTH(today()), 1))))
+COUNTUNIQUE(filter(V!A4:A&V!$B$4:$B,(DATE(YEAR(V!A4:A), MONTH(V!A4:A), 1)=DATE(YEAR(today()), MONTH(today()), 1)))) but I think is not the solution as well because the countunique gives me 1 even when there is no data for those dates

Comment: the expected result for this month should be 8 not 12

Comment: why 8? how did you calculate it?